# Bootstrap3 hover color disabled after click it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap3  `dropdown-menu`. Once I open and close the menu which contains subcategories, its hover color got disabled.

For example,

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#"> item1 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"> item2 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> submenu </a></li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#"> sub item1 </a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

My customized css for this,

```
.menu ul li a:hover {
background: #6f9be2;
```

}

When I check with developer tools on my browser, it got disabled.
How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it is because you are only selecting children `<a>`'s of the first `<ul>` element.  You have another `<ul>` element within the first one with more `<li>`'s.  Maybe try `.menu .nav.navbar-nav ul li a:hover { background: #6f9be2;}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
ul li a:hover {
   background-color: #6f9be2 !important;;
}
```

```css
 ul li a:hover {
background-color: #6f9be2 !important;;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#"> item1 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"> item2 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> submenu </a></li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#"> sub item1 </a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```